# Not able to display page owner with presence in layout

Tags: sharepoint-server, page-layout

We have added SharePointWebControls:UserField to display the page owner information but not able to show owner presence(Such as Online, Away, In Meeting like lync) on page layout using out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to enter in a manual HTML and add his/her email to the markup:

```
<span><img border=”0″ valign=”middle” height=”12″ width=”12″ src="/_layouts/images/imnhdr.gif" onload="IMNRC('email@domain.com')" id=’sampleId1′ ShowOfflinePawn=1/>Joe Blow</span>
```

Excerpt from: https://isharepoint.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/sharepoint-and-displaying-ocs-presence-using-javascript/

Comment: Thank you Mike for updating the same I am using Page layout and  on page layout Page owner information is coming User details such as Email Id and User name but not Image, only I want image in the see the below tag which I am using page <SharePointWebControls:UserField  FieldName="345fe-23drjnr-344-ghtk" runat="server" id="COP" />